# assigning delegate subscribe event to a List

Tags: c#, events, delegates, onchange

Here is my problem : I have one delegate which I subscribe to from another class, that's alright. What I'd like is each time something subscribe to this delegate it raise an event that tells me the invocation list has changed and how +1 or -1...
I searched for an Onchange event in invocationlist but didn't find anything..

Form1:

```
namespace EventsOnDelegates
{
public delegate void DEL_delegate1(Double AValue);
public delegate void DEL_delegate2(Boolean AsecondValue);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public DEL_delegate1 SetValueCbk;
    public EventHandler InvocationListChange;
    private Form2 FormwithLabel;
    int invoclength;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormwithLabel = new Form2(this);
        FormwithLabel.Show();  
        /*the question part*/
        /*I'd like to add an onchange event that tells me if the invocation list has changed and how + or -*/
        InvocationListChange += new EventHandler(SetValueCbk.GetInvocationList(),InvocationListHaschanged);          
    }
    protected virtual void InvocationListHaschanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    invoclength = SetValueCbk.GetInvocationList().Length;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(invoclength);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random newRandNum = new Random();
        Double newNumber = newRandNum.NextDouble();
        SetValueCbk(newNumber);
    }
}
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(){}
    public Form2(Form1 Form1link)
        :this()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1link.SetValueCbk  += new DEL_delegate1(this.SetValueCbkFN);
    }
    protected void SetValueCbkFN(Double value)
    {
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explicit event declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx) for that `event` field :

```
private EventHandler meEvent;

public event EventHandler MeEvent
{
    add { meEvent += value; MeEventInvocationListChanged(); }
    remove { meEvent -= value; MeEventInvocationListChanged(); }
}
```

**EDIT :** *( Fitting this into your question )*

instead of your `InvocationListHasChanged` method you can create :

```
void InvokationListChanged(int dir)
{
    string msg = dir < 0 ? "Someone unsubscribed from the event" : "Someone subscribed to the event";
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke( new MethodInvoker( () => { label1.Text = msg; });
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = msg;
    }
}
```

And then change `public DEL_delegate1 SetValueCbk;` to :

```
private DEL_delegate1 m_SetValueCbk;

public event Del_delegate1 SetValueCbk
{
    add { m_SetValueCbk+= value; InvokationListChanged(1); }
    remove { m_SetValueCbk-= value; InvokationListChanged(-1); }
}
```

Now whenever some other object subscribe to `SetValueCbk` your `label1.Text` will change to `"Someone subscribed to the event"` and whenever some object unsubscribe from `SetValueCbk` your `label1.Text` will change to `"Someone unsubscribed from the event"`

Comment: Don't understand... what is MeEventInvocationListChanged()? where is the link to the invocation list from this delegate?? thanks by the way.

Comment: That's not a property, it's an event, it's simply an event with explicit, rather than implicit, add/remove handlers.

Comment: @Servy Yes, thank you for the hint. Edited it and added link to msdn :)